Why is validate-azure-ad-token in policy fragment with context variable not working
I am using Policy Fragments in Azure API Management to make my policies reusable.
One of the policies fragments validates the Authentication token from the request using the validate-azure-ad-token policy.
The fragment looks like this:
<fragment>
    <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="<my tenant id>">
        <audiences>
            <audience>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Audience"))</audience>
        </audiences>
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="roles" match="all">
                <value>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Role"))</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-azure-ad-token>
</fragment>

In the policy on my API, I first set the context variables, then I include the fragment:
<set-variable name="Audience" value="{{Audience-Named-Value}}" />
<set-variable name="Role" value="{{Role-Named-Value}}" />
<include-fragment fragment-id="ValidateOAuthFragment" />

When doing this, I get the a 401 response with the following error: Invalid Azure AD JWT.
The strange thing is that, when I explicitly use my named value for the audience in the fragment, the policy succeeds. So <audience>{{Audience-Named-Value}}</audience> works. But, of course that's not what I want, because I want to dynamically set the Audience.
The part for the Role does work and gives no issues.
I do have a workaround, that is using the validate-jwt policy instead. There I can use a context variable for the Audience, but I wonder why validate-azure-ad-token doesn't like it.
Any ideas/suggestions?


I do have a workaround, that is using the validate-jwt policy instead. There I can use a context variable for the Audience, but I wonder why validate-azure-ad-token doesn't like it.

It looks like element  audiences  is not accepting policy expressions and only takes named values as {{}}  but as per the Validate-azure-ad-token Policy Elements, policy expression is allowed. So I have created a github issue for the same.
For the time being, you can use Named values to pass the values dynamically in policy fragment instead of assigning it to a set-variable.
<fragment>
    <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="<tenant id>">
        <audiences>
            <audience>{{Audience-Named-Value}}</audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-azure-ad-token>
</fragment>

It works just fine.

If you still want to pass the values from  context parameter then I would suggest you to use validate-jwt policy instead as its a stable policy.
Meanwhile you can refer the github issue raised to get the latest update.
